# Integrating WPF Validation into MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have some ValidationRules that are working correctly.  I'm just wondering what the best way to integrate this with my ViewModel would be.

I have an (overly simple) method—HasAnyErrors—that walks the control tree checking for errors, but I'm not sure how to expose these results to my ViewModel.  In other words, what should I do if I have an ICommand that can only execute if there are not validation errors?

The best I could come up with was just handling the click event of the button, and then manually invoking the ViewModel's command if there were no errors.

```
    private void Button_Click_RunCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (this.HasAnyErrors())
            return;
        (this.DataContext as SomeViewModel).SomeCommand.Execute(null);
    }
```

It's not the most elegant solution; but it appears to work.  Is there a more elegant solution available?

**BREAK**

For completeness here are the validation methods (most will be extension methods before too long).  They (appear to) work fine, but I'm sure at least someone will wonder what they look like.

```
    bool HasAnyErrors() {
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        GetErrors(this, errors);
        return errors.Any();
    }

    void GetErrors(DependencyObject obj, List<string> errors) {
        foreach (UIElement child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj).OfType<UIElement>()) {
            if (child is TextBox)
                AddErrorIfExists(child as UIElement, errors);
            GetErrors(child, errors);
        }
    }

    private void AddErrorIfExists(UIElement element, List<string> errors) {
        if (Validation.GetHasError(element))
            errors.Add(Validation.GetErrors(element)[0].ErrorContent.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: It's unrelated, but it would probably be worthwhile switching your validation method here to use `IEnumerable<T>` implementations - as it stands, if the very first control you check has an error you will still go through and check **every** item in the visual tree unnecessarily before you return

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you could determine whether or not their are any validation methods against the view model itself instead of using `Validation.GetErrors()` - if you are implementing `IDataErrorInfo` then it is probably going to be simpler.

If that is the case you can take the validation state of the view model into account within the `CanExecute` method of the command to which the button is bound.

Comment: Isn't IDataErrorInfo used for your data objects—like `customer` - whereby you would set errors to true if the customer entered an SSN that was 10 digits?  Right now I'm just working with showing the user that they entered a string for an integer property.

Comment: Regardless, custom validation rules are always bound to the UI.  Doesn't there have to be some way for the ViewModel to know that some of the ValidationRules are in an invalid state?

Comment: Good point, this approach wouldn't take into account UI-driven validations.  I have only limited experience of working with non-VM validations but I guess you could do something with attached properties to pass the error state back to the view model.

Comment: I've been struggling to figure out a clear idea along the lines of using a property (attached sounds promising) to pass to the ViewModel.  Do you have any sort of closely-related example of this you've already written for something else?

Comment: I've not implemented anything like that before, but I was thinking of sticking an interface with a string indexer on the view model.  Then you could set up a couple of attached properties (one to specify the view model, one to bind to the validation properties) that as-cast the view model to your interface in the property changed handler and set validation details through the indexer.  I'd throw together an example but I'm only on an iPad atm!

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. The class BookView.xaml.cs shows how to synchronize the WPF validation state with the underlying ViewModel.

In the sample it is used for parsing errors. In this concrete case a parsing error comes when the user enters 'abc' in the Pages TextBox. Pages is bound to an integer value and so 'abc' cannot be parsed.